# Why system call like WRITE(2) doesn't provide buffer to increase speed?

Tags: operating-system, buffer, system-calls

Compared to functions like `printf()`, system call `write()` is usually slower because it has no buffer. But why not provide a built-in buffer in `write()`. OSes' speed is important, isn't it?

I am not familiar with operating system, it quite confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are the low level calls to the operating system on which the higher level (buffered) methods like `fread`, `fwrite`, `fflush` and so on  are implemented.

> OSes' speed is important, isn't it?

Yes it is.  But it is assumed that application is going to make `write()` calls efficiently.  If it needs buffering, it should use `fwrite`.

---

So if `read` is not buffered and buffering is more efficient, why don't they hide it?

Because buffering is not *always* more efficient.  In fact, for some use-cases a buffered stream does more copying than using `write` directly.  For bulk I/O operations this extra copy leads to slower I/O.